# split string until a 5-7 digit number is found in python

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I have strings like the following:

```
1338516 -...pair - 5pk 1409093 -...re Wax 3Pk
1409085 -...dtnr - 5pk 1415090 -...accessories
490663 - 3 pack 1490739 -...2 - 3 pack
```

What I'm trying to do is, split these strings so that the first string is `1338516 -...pair - 5pk` and the second one is `1409093 -...re Wax 3Pk`.

Currently, I'm able to extract the numbers using the following code:

```
list(filter(lambda k: '...' in k, reqText))
lst1 = ''.join(lst)
numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', lst1)
numbers1 = [x for x in numbers if len(x) > 3]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use split with a pattern:

```
[^\S\n]+(?=\d{5,7}\b)
```

**Explanation**

- `[^\S\n]+` Match 1 or more spaces without a newline
- `(?=\d{5,7}\b)` Positive lookahead, assert 5-7 digits to the right followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7vJHui/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"[^\S\n]+(?=\d{5,7}\b)"

lst = [
    "1338516 -...pair - 5pk 1409093 -...re Wax 3Pk",
    "1409085 -...dtnr - 5pk 1415090 -...accessories",
    "490663 - 3 pack 1490739 -...2 - 3 pack"
]

for s in lst:
    print(re.split(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['1338516 -...pair - 5pk', '1409093 -...re Wax 3Pk']
['1409085 -...dtnr - 5pk', '1415090 -...accessories']
['490663 - 3 pack', '1490739 -...2 - 3 pack']
```

---

Another option could be a matching approach:

```
\b\d{5,7}\b.*?(?=[^\S\n]+\d{5,7}\b|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X9z4LO/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(.+?)\s*\b(\d{5,7}\b.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0atBcU/1).

In Python, use a raw string literal to declare this regex:

```py
pattern = r'^(.+?)\s*\b(\d{5,7}\b.*)'
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.+?)` - Group 1: one or more (but as few as possible) occurrences of any char other than line break chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d{5,7}\b.*)` - Group 2: five-seven digit number, word boundary and the rest of the line.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/rq0p6H):

```py
import re
text = "1338516 -...pair - 5pk 1409093 -...re Wax 3Pk"
pattern = r'^(.+?)\s*\b(\d{5,7}\b.*)'
m = re.search(pattern, text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => 1338516 -...pair - 5pk
    print(m.group(2)) # => 1409093 -...re Wax 3Pk
```

If you need to use it in a Pandas dataframe, you can use

```py
df[['result_col_1', 'result_col_2']] = df['source'].str.extract(pattern, expand=True)
```

Comment: Why does this create empty elements `('')` in the output list?

Comment: @VishalA. It does not, see my Python demo.